# How to fix 'Webhook signature verification failed' in PayPal Node.js webhook?

Tags: node.js, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

While implementing PayPal webhooks in a Node.js application, I encountered an `401 Unauthorized` error with the message "Webhook signature verification failed". This issue arises when I make a `POST` request to `http://localhost:3001/paypal/subscriptions/webhook` using `Postman`.

**Background:**

To simulate webhook events, I've been using [Webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) to capture PayPal's webhook calls and extract necessary headers. These headers are then manually added to Postman requests to mimic the actual webhook call from PayPal. The headers include:

- **`paypal-auth-algo`**
- **`paypal-cert-url`**
- **`paypal-transmission-id`**
- **`paypal-transmission-sig`**
- **`paypal-transmission-time`**

Despite ensuring the correctness of these headers, the verification of the webhook signature consistently fails.

#### Code:

```js
paypalRouter.post("/subscriptions/webhook", async (req, res) => {

  console.log("Received webhook event", req.body); 

  try {
   
    console.log('Headers:', {
      'paypal-auth-algo': req.headers['paypal-auth-algo'],
      'paypal-cert-url': req.headers['paypal-cert-url'],
      'paypal-transmission-id': req.headers['paypal-transmission-id'],
      'paypal-transmission-sig': req.headers['paypal-transmission-sig'],
      'paypal-transmission-time': req.headers['paypal-transmission-time'],
    });
    const webhookEvent = req.body;

    console.log("Webhook event received:", webhookEvent.event_type);


    const verification = {
      auth_algo: req.headers['paypal-auth-algo'],
      cert_url: req.headers['paypal-cert-url'],
      transmission_id: req.headers['paypal-transmission-id'],
      transmission_sig: req.headers['paypal-transmission-sig'],
      transmission_time: req.headers['paypal-transmission-time'],
      webhook_id: process.env.WEBHOOK_ID,
      webhook_event: webhookEvent,
    };
    console.log('Final Verification Request Payload:', JSON.stringify(verification, null, 2));

    console.log('Verification Payload:', verification);

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

    const authResponse = await axios.post(
      "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
      params,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        auth: {
          username: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
          password: process.env.PAYPAL_SECRET,
        },
      }
    );

    const accessToken = authResponse.data.access_token;

    

    const verifyResponse = await axios.post(
      "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature",
      verification,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        },
      }
    );

 
    if (verifyResponse.data.verification_status === "SUCCESS") {
      // Handle different event types as needed
      if (webhookEvent.event_type === "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED") {
        // Extracting the custom_id and subscription ID from the webhook event
        const userId = webhookEvent.resource.custom_id; // Adjusted based on actual data structure
        const subscriptionId = webhookEvent.resource.id; // Adjusted based on actual data structure

        console.log(`Attempting to confirm subscription for user ${userId} with subscription ID ${subscriptionId}`);

        try {
          // Updating the user's subscription status to 'confirmed'
          const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              { _id: userId, subscriptionId: subscriptionId }, 
              { $set: { subscriptionStatus: 'confirmed' }},
              { new: true }
          );

          if (updatedUser) {
              console.log("Subscription confirmed for user:", userId);
          } else {
              console.log("No matching user document to update or subscription ID mismatch.");
          }

          return res.status(200).send('Subscription confirmed');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error confirming subscription:", error);
          return res.status(500).send("Error updating subscription status.");
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Failed to verify webhook signature:", verifyResponse.data);
      return res.status(401).send('Webhook signature verification failed');
    }
  }
  }
});
```

#### Console.logs

```js
Received webhook event: {}

Headers: {
  'paypal-auth-algo': 'SHA...',
  'paypal-cert-url': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT...',
  'paypal-transmission-id': 'a5d...',
  'paypal-transmission-sig': 'Rrwi...',
  'paypal-transmission-time': '2024....'
}
Webhook event received: undefined
Final Verification Request Payload: {
  "auth_algo": "SHA-....",
  "cert_url": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-...",
  "transmission_id": "a5d....",
  "transmission_sig": "Rrw...",
  "transmission_time": "2024....",
  "webhook_id": "string",
  "webhook_event": {}
}
Failed to verify webhook signature: { verification_status: 'FAILURE' }
```

**Research and Attempts:**

- I've verified that the headers mimic what PayPal sends for a real webhook event.
- I've ensured that the environment variables for the PayPal client ID and secret are correctly set and my `WEBHOOK_ID` as well.
- Searched Stack Overflow (SO) and found similar questions, but those solutions (e.g., checking the environment URL, ensuring headers are correct) did not resolve my issue.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any common pitfalls or specific configurations for PayPal webhook verification that I might have missed?
2. Could the issue stem from how I'm setting up the headers in Postman or a misunderstanding of the PayPal webhook verification process?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if all the headers are correct, and the webhook ID is correct, that leaves the data (webhookEvent) as the most likely culprit. For verification it needs to be sent back 1:1 in exactly the same order as PayPal sent it, with no whitespace change nor any other change

Comment: thank you for your answer, I noticed that on this  [website](https://webhook.site/)  the only header that remains the same is `paypal-auth-algo` Once I make a  `POST` request to the website with the client side, I'm unsure if my headers are passing correctly because `paypal-cert-url`, `paypal-transmission-id`, `paypal-transmission-sig` and `paypal-transmission-time` are different values each time I make a `POST` request, how can I make sure these headers are passed correctly in postman?

Comment: How do you test your app locally? Are you perhaps using [smee.io](https://smee.io)? If that's the case, smee.io prettifies the payload before tunneling it back to your application, and you have to minify it again before you can verify the signature

Comment: Hello @Pieterjan, I'm using this website: https://webhook.site and I'm testing my app locally with Postman if that answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue, as Paypal is very concerned about its webhooks security, I can't run my webhook locally with Postman, the solution was to download and set up **ngrok** and change my webhook URL to the URL **ngrok** generated for me and add "/paypal/subscriptions/webhook" at the end of the URL something like this:

`https://ngrok-url/paypal/subscriptions/webhook`

on "Sandbox Webhooks"